# Language switching issue with Django 1.8.4 and uWSGI config with several processes

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm facing a strange issue when I switch the language on a `Django 1.8.4` project that I have deployed on production with `Nginx` + `uWSGI`. The problem is that when I switch the language, somehow every language I change is "remembered", and every time I refresh the page the site language changes to a different language that I have used before. It seems like each process of `uWSGI` is storing a language itself. When I run my project with the `Django` server locally, it works like a charm, and when I set just 1 process to the `uWSGI` config file, it also works properly, but as soon as I set just 2 processes it is broken again. I have been using:

- `Django 1.8.4`
- `uWSGI==2.0.11.2`

Below the `uWSGI` config file I have:

`uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:8080
chdir=/path/to/code
wsgi-file=wsgi.py
need-app=true
processes=8
master=true
enable-threads=true
thunder-lock=true
single-interpreter=true
plugin=python
```

As I commented above if I leave the config file with `processes=1` it works as should.

What I mean with "switch the language" is exactly what is writing on this section of the `Django doc`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language. I have a utility like this:

```
def activate_language(request, language_code):
    """
    Explicitly setting the active language.
    As to the doc:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view#s-explicitly-setting-the-active-language
    :param language_code: the language code: en, es, da, and so on.
    :return:
    """
    activate(language_code)
    request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language_code
```

After the excellent questions done, I would like to put more details here. I'm using this `session engine`:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

and I have tested that the value of the session on the DB is updated properly:

```
In [13]: Session.objects.get(pk='lrx8sdzbabztc8wifiab5i5gmqiwuxnn').get_decoded()
Out[13]: {u'_language': u'es'}

In [14]: Session.objects.get(pk='lrx8sdzbabztc8wifiab5i5gmqiwuxnn').get_decoded()
Out[14]: {u'_language': u'en'}

In [15]: Session.objects.get(pk='lrx8sdzbabztc8wifiab5i5gmqiwuxnn').get_decoded()
Out[15]: {u'_language': u'da'}
```

but still the issue persists even when this value changes as should. I have some clues about this though. When I use any of the following `session engines`:

```
"django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"
"django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
```

it works like a charm. So could it be related with the way of getting this value when using the `cached_db` engine?

I will appreciate any help you can give me about that issue. Thanks in advance to all the community.

Comment: When you say -- you switch language - do you mean just change LANGUAGE_CODE in settings or what else?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @iamkhush, exactly what is in this section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/#explicitly-setting-the-active-language

Comment: So, you mean, that for example you have a language A and then you switch to language B, then later you refresh the page, it goes back to language A?

Comment: More or less that, yes. It keeps switching between A and B when we refresh the page several times. Thanks again for you comment!

Comment: Can you check in your session table ( or memcache or wherever you have implemented sessions storage)  if the value is updated or not?

Comment: Yes, the value is updated properly. I'm using this `session engine`: `SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'`. I will update the question, because when I use any of `"django.contrib.sessions.backends.file"` or `"django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"` it works properly too :). You gave me a good clue @iamkhush ;). Thanks a lot for that. Do you have any other suggestion? +1 for this excellent question :). Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, then what about the Cache Backend? Are you using `django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache` . If yes, try some other cache backend like Memcache.

Comment: @iamkhush I don't have how to thanks you about your valuable help. That solved my issue! I set up `Memcache` and everything worked like a charm :). I know I miss-read the [`Django doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#s-using-cached-sessions) about that ;), it is very clear there. In any case you have saved me a lot of time mate! Thanks again for all your time and help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally got this fixed. Which I couldn't have done without the help of @iamkhush, who with his great questions directed me to the fix. The problem was solved setting up the `Memcache`. The key of this was on the [`Django session doc`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#s-using-cached-sessions) itself:

`You should only use cache-based sessions if you’re using the Memcached cache backend.`

And that was exactly my problem, that I was using `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db` as `SESSION_ENGINE` but I was not using `Memcache`. So it is solved now.